# Camera dismissed when opening SettingsCharm in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Hi am creating a camera application . For implementing this i used [CameraCatureUI](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI-Sample-845a53ac#content)

My problem is that `Camera` cancels or dismissed when i open `Settings` charm.
 How we can prevent this strange behaviour?

Comment: It's considered polite to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera canceled state is giving you a hint on what you should do with your own UI. If the user displays the settings (or causes cancelled) you should do one of two things:

1. Dismiss your own UI (most likely)
2. Reset the camera request

Best of luck!